# Facebook SDK Freeze My Server

Tags: php, facebook

I'm first time fb sdk user,

I am creating my first app the idea is to iterate with for loop throught and array of 5 groups in users groups list, in this list I get the gid and later check the messages from this stream using FQL, if there's a message in the stream don't post, very simple.

All of this happens in a loop.

The problem is that I set a timeout(20) for each item of the loop, but i don't know why my whole server freezes during the script execution.

I tried this on heroku and on my local server, both servers crash until the script completed.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Can we see the script?

Comment: Sure, i edited my messagem, please check.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `crash until the script completed`? Does the server actually crash? Or does it stop responding temporarily but after successfully completing the script it comes back to normal?

Comment: Sorry for the crash, not the best word to use. After completing it comes back to normal, it freezes my server, i can't access any webpage when script is running, when it finishes server is back to normal. In heroku i can't execute any other script during execution of this loop, same thing happen on ubuntu server.

Comment: nobody has an answer to this issue?

Comment: Ok I solved myself using Javascript, Thanks anyway.